# JOIN returns duplicated results, should I worry about that?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, join

I'm using `JOIN` with MySQL to select an article and all comments related to it, but I   realized that when I select an article and there's more than one comment for it, I get the same article duplicated by the number of comments. For example:
I have the table `articles` with the following columns:
1. `id`
2. `article`
And the table `comments` with the following columns:
1. `c_id`
2. `body`
3. `a_id`

MySQL query I tried to use:

```
SELECT  * FROM `articles`
JOIN`comments`
ON (`articles`.id = `comments`.a_id)
WHERE `articles`.id = 134
```

And this is the final result:

```
id  article   c_id  body        a_id
134 Article1    2   Comment1    134
134 Article1    3   Comment2    134
134 Article1    8   Comment3    134
```

So my question is: Since I'm getting the same `article` column's value for every comment, 
does this slows the MySQL query or my web application by anyway? since I'm requesting more data then what I really need.
I can separate the query to 2 simple `SELECT` queries, but this will be overkill, right?

Thanks for reading.

**Edit:**
What if I the `article` column's value is bigger, something that contains 1k+ characters, will it make since to duplicate it?

Comment: You may want to think about the total amount of load that is going into this - you may be trying to optimize something that is more than fast enough already. This seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I'm getting the same article column's value for every comment,
>   does this slows the MySQL query or my web application by anyway? since
>   I'm requesting more data then what I really need.

Since the database is transmitting more bytes than it needs to there is performance cost associated with this but it may not be noticeable.

> I can separate the query to 2 simple SELECT queries, but this will be overkill, right?

Its hard to say without measuring. If the value of article was a Gigabyte instead of a few characters then you would probably want to do two selects instead of one.

Comment: What if I the article column's value is bigger, something that contains 1k+ characters, will it make since to duplicate it?

Comment: I would probably do two queries in that case but that's my bias. You could test to see what the actual differences are if you wanted to rigorously determine if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

You could get all of the articles you want to display in one query, then do another mysql call for all of the comments `WHERE comments.a_id IN (1,2,5,6,9,10)`, then in your application pull the relevant comments for the article you are displaying.

I think this will be more efficient than getting the comments in separate queries for each article.

Comment: A real high-load targeted solution. I like it.

Comment: I could be misinterpreting your answer, but I think that converting a join into separate database calls for each table is not generally good advice (unless maybe your ORM is doing that, and then the optimization is often to force the join).

Comment: +1, but I'm not willing to display more than one article in any page, so it doesn't apply to my web application.

Answer (score 1):

This is ok. Splitting into two queries would require two trips to the database, executing similar query twice etc. In most settings that is more expensive than getting more data - hopefully the protocol used by the client to communicate with the database would optimize this. MySQL does have an option to [use compression between client and server](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol#Compression) - that should optimize the data transmitted.

If this is critical for your application you should benchmark and choose the one that works best.

If it is not go with the approach that is simple to implement - do a perf / load test of the entire application, find the bottlenecks and fix those.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to select more info than you need rather than have to go back to get more from the database in another query.

In this case, I can't imagine that you are slowing down your system too much by grabbing `article` records too.  if you're worried about it, don't use that `select *` but rather explicitly call columns like so:

```
SELECT `comments`.c_id , `comments`.body, `comments`.a_id
FROM `articles`
    JOIN `comments` ON `articles`.id = `comments`.a_id
WHERE `articles`.id = 134
```

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm currently doing, I just used `SELECT *` for the question.

Comment: I see. Well, with all things performance-related, you have to test.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly is slower if you execute two queries separately. 
If you have the "article.id" before you execute the query, you don't need to use JOIN.